# Simple Table Join with access to joined table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a simple table of items. Call them "Parts".

Each part can have zero or more related entries in a seperate table, call them "SubParts".
A simple view of the tables is, as you would probably expect:

```
Parts
-----
PartID int (PK)
PartName varchar

SubParts
--------
SubPartID int (PK)
PartID int (FK_Parts)
SubPartName varchar
SubPartAdded datetime
```

I would like to return all parts from the primary table, but also have access to the LATEST (order by SubPartAdded DESC) related SubPart if it exists.

My confusion is that there are a 1M+ entries in the subparts table (for many different parts) and I only need the latest one for the current part, if it exists.

Earlier I wrote a statement that performed a left join between the Parts table and a derived table of related Subparts (which works) but the derived table *seems* to return ALL rows in the subparts table causing a performance hit. I essentially need to do a TOP 1 and order by DESC in the derived select statement, to prefilter the subparts by PartID (and some other columns). However as I cant seem to make reference to the Parts table (outer) columns in the derived select statement, I cant add a WHERE clause to the derived table.

I have also tried the following snippet which does execute, but doesnt return any related records:

```
    SELECT  p.PartName, sp.SubPartName, sp.SubPartAdded
    FROM    Parts p 
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT TOP 1 SubPartID, SubpartAdded, PartID FROM SubParts ORDER BY SubPartAdded) AS sp
               ON sp.PartID = p.PartID
```

I imagine the "TOP 1" statement is executing against the whole SubParts table, before being filtered by the "ON" statement (?)

Ultimately I need to use some columns from the Subparts table in multiple locations thoughout the main stored proc, so I dont simply want a correlated subquery as this would need to be called multiple times.

(This proc will return multiple parts on each execution. ie. The proc will not be filtered by a single PartID)

I hope this is pretty clear?
It sounds like it should have a very simple solution, but I'm currently stumped!
(Compatibility with SQL Server 2K and above is required)

Regards
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work back to SQL Server 2000.

```
SELECT  PartName, SubPartName, SubPartAdded
FROM    Parts
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  SubParts.PartID, SubParts.SubPartName SubParts.SubPartAdded
            FROM    SubParts
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  PartID, MAX(SubPartAdded) [SubPartAdded]
                        FROM    SubParts
                        GROUP BY PartID
                    ) MaxSubPart
                        ON MaxSubPart.PartID = SubParts.PartID
                        AND MaxSubPart.SubPartAdded = SubParts.SubPartAdded
        ) Subpart
            ON SubPart.PartID = Parts.PartID
```

There are more efficient and elegent ways to do this in later versions (OUTER APPLY, or Window functions), but I am not certain how many of the methods are backwards compatitble to SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

You need a derived table to extract last subparts. Then you can filter subparts joining it to derived table by id and SubPartAdded columns:

```
SELECT  p.PartName, sp.SubPartName, sp.SubPartAdded
FROM    Parts p 
LEFT JOIN SubParts sp
  ON p.PartID = sp.PartID
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT PartID, max (SubPartAdded) MaxSubPartAdded
    FROM SubParts 
   GROUP BY PartID
) AS MaxSP
  ON sp.PartID = MaxSP.PartID
 AND sp.SubPartAdded = MaxSP.MaxSubPartAdded
```

If Sql Server 2005 or newer:

```
SELECT  p.PartName, sp.SubPartName, sp.SubPartAdded
FROM    Parts p 
OUTER APPLY
(
   select top 1 
          SubPartName, SubPartAdded
     from SubParts 
    where SubParts.PartID = p.PartID
   order by SubPartAdded desc
) sp
```

Comment: Your first query needs a `GROUP BY`, not `ORDER BY` in the MaxSP Subquery. Even with this correction though it will return all sub parts. You would need a where clause to state something like `WHERE MaxSp.PartID IS NOT NULL OR sp.PartID IS NULL` this would remove the subparts that are not the newest, while still allowing Parts with no subparts.

Comment: @GarethD I messed up editing. It should be expressed in join clause.